# Dynamic grid columns added again after destroy

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

I'm trying to add columns to a ExtJS grid in `initComponent()` using `this.columns.push()`.

This is working fine, but when I destroy the view and create it again the columns are duplicated. It seems ExtJS is keeping some state of the previous instance. I even tried to reset the columns array in `destroy()` but can't eliminate this strange behaviour.

See this [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16oq) for the code.

Comment: Add this to the first line of initComponent: `this.columns = Ext.Array.clone(this.columns);`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thanks this fixes my problem. Could you please explain why this is needed? And you could add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it should work

```
var grid, columnsArr = [];
grid.reconfigure(undefined, columnsArr);
```

the first parameter is a store reference. pass a reference to new store if you wish to change the store as well